# I'd like to create a table with PHP, but I don't know how to do it

Tags: php, html, forms

I have to create a table with the following values:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDEGd.png)

I guess create this table but not with these values. I have a form that I have to enter a number for example 5 and I have to create a table with 5 rows and 5 columns then I have another value in the form that is used to check if the number is a multiple of the number entered in the box.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Form 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["length"]) && isset($_POST["multiples"])) {
                $multiples = $_POST["multiples"];
                $length = $_POST["length"];
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($j = 1; $j <= $length; $j++) {
                        if ($j % 2 == 0) {
                            echo "<td bgcolor=red>$j</td> ";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td bgcolor=yellow>$j</td> ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            } else {
                echo <<<EOT
        <form method="post" action="forms1.php">
            <label for="logitud">Side length : </label> 
            <input type="number" name="length" > 
            <label for="multiples">Multiples: </label> 
            <input type="number" name="multiples" > 
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
EOT;
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph9AV.png)

If someone can help me I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately what you are looking to do is make a square that is `$length` by `$multiples`, so in order to do that you want to take into account `$length * $multiples`.

There are ways to do this with an inner `for` loop as you are doing, however since you are already familiar with `%` (MOD) you can simplify things a bit.

(Also, whenever you are given an assigment/test/whatever like this, ignore the whole form stuff and work on the logic first. Once that is good, you can easily add in the form part.)

```php
<table border="1">
<?php
    $multiples = 5;
    $length = 5;

    // Loop from 1 to 25 (or whatever  L * M equals)
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($length * $multiples); $i++) {
        // We are using a one-based start, so whenever our MOD works out to one
        // here we are at the start of a row
        if (1 === $i % $multiples) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }

        // Same logic for coloring
        if (0 === $i % 2) {
            echo "<td bgcolor=red>$i</td> ";
        } else {
            echo "<td bgcolor=yellow>$i</td> ";
        }

        // Being one-based, when our MOD is zero we are at the end of a row
        if (0 === $i % $multiples) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

*(edit)*

Here's a version that uses two loops and calculates the cell's value each time. The `$k` logic is a little complex but hopefully makes sens.

```php
    $multiples = 5;
    $length = 5;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $multiples; $j++) {
            $k = (($i - 1) * $length) + $j;
            if (0 === $k % 2) {
                echo "<td bgcolor=red>$k</td> ";
            } else {
                echo "<td bgcolor=yellow>$k</td> ";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

More people would probably keep track of a counter independently:

```php
    $multiples = 5;
    $length = 5;
    $k = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $multiples; $j++) {
            if (0 === $k % 2) {
                echo "<td bgcolor=red>$k</td> ";
            } else {
                echo "<td bgcolor=yellow>$k</td> ";
            }
            $k++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```